# Error with R function using Knitr in Lyx

Tags: r, latex, knitr, lyx

I am getting an error when using the summary() function using
Knitr in Lyx. The functions preceding it works.

```
<<>>=
library(faraway)
head(teengamb)
mdl <- lm(gamble ~ sex + status, data=teengamb) 
summary(mdl)
@
```

I am inputing this code through Insert Tex Code in Lyx. I just tested I can run summary(teengamb) but not summary(mdl). Both codes work in RStudio.

The error is "Undefined Control Sequence" with description "\end{verbatim} ..."

Comment: Can you be more specific about the error you get? Do you get the error if you put this in a Lyx document by itself?

Comment: I wasn't being specific, I'd updated my post to include more details.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not able to replicate your problem; I'm running Lyx 2.0.4 on Ubuntu. Have you tried marking the code as a Sweave chunk (using the dropdown styles) instead of using `Insert > Tex Code`? What version of Lyx etc and what OS are you using?

Comment: I am using Lyx 2.0.4 on Mac. I just tried Sweave instead and it worked, guess I am only having problem with knitr.

Comment: To follow up on @mrdwab's comment, his suggestion also worked for me, but I had to make sure that Rnw(knitr) was moved to the 'Selected' column under Document > Settings > Modules.

Comment: @SaberCN I cannot replicate the problem either with LyX 2.0.4/Ubuntu. Can you post the full error log? (e.g. on http://pastebin.com/) BTW, what is your version of knitr? `packageVersion('knitr')`

Comment: @Yihui I didn't see your comment until now. I posted the log to http://pastebin.com/t2ZL1CnA , the error starts at line 234.

Comment: @SaberCN Someone asked me a similar question after your post, and finally it turned out that the reason was his LaTeX does not support `'` (apostrophe) in the `verbatim` environment, which is really weird and I have no idea how that could be possible. To verify your problem, see if you can compile this minimal document: http://pastebin.com/72n9RCEm

Comment: @Yihui I saved your code to a tex file, imported it to Lyx, loaded knitr and compiled with no problem. This is the only instance I get error with knitr. For example, I don't get any error with this code, <<>>= library(faraway) mdl<-lm(total~ratio+expend, data=sat) summary(mdl) @

Comment: @SaberCN How about setting `options(show.signif.stars = FALSE)`?

Comment: @Yihui Yes! It worked after I added this code at the beginning. Can you explain the issue behind this?

Comment: @SaberCN it is too weird; I cannot reproduce it, nor can I explain it...

Comment: @SaberCN I have found out the real reason. See my edit below.

Answer (score 6):

This problem has been solved in [`knitr`](https://github.com/yihui/knitr) after version 1.1. You do not need to change anything in LyX or R. Install **knitr** from CRAN:

```
install.packages('knitr')
```

**Please ignore both answers below:**

---

I have finally found out the reason for this error (this is the deepest bug I have ever seen). It is because the `upquote` package does not work if the `T1` encoding is declared after it is loaded, e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
'
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

But if we move `upquote` after `fontenc`, it works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{upquote}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
'
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Or just do not use the T1 encoding -- uncheck the checkbox before the font encoding in the preferences:

[image]

The reason that Ubuntu users were not able to reproduce the problem was because `upquote.sty` was from R's texmf tree instead of the one in TeXLive, and R's version of `upquote` works.

The other way to fix the problem is to add R's texmf tree to MikTeX under Windows.

**Please ignore the answer below:**

---

Since `options(show.signif.stars = FALSE)` worked, I'm posting it as one possible answer, but this is still a very weird problem to me. Setting `show.signif.stars = FALSE` removes the significance codes from the results below (which was from `summary(mdl)`):

```
Call:
lm(formula = gamble ~ sex + status, data = teengamb)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-35.873 -15.755  -3.007  10.924 111.586 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  60.2233    15.1347   3.979 0.000255 ***
sex         -35.7094     9.4899  -3.763 0.000493 ***
status       -0.5855     0.2727  -2.147 0.037321 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1 

Residual standard error: 27.99 on 44 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.2454, Adjusted R-squared: 0.2111 
F-statistic: 7.154 on 2 and 44 DF,  p-value: 0.002042
```

The error came from the line `Signif. codes`, and I do not understand why any of these characters could possibly cause errors in LaTeX: all of them are ASCII and should work inside the `verbatim` environment.

From the comments above, neither @mrdwab nor me could reproduce the problem. I guess there must be something weird about the OP's LaTeX installation.